# Spring JPA @query image

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I need to get image saved in postgresql database using custom query in repository.
Currently i save image to database as byte[] with mime-type, file name and also create 2 thumbnail image in the same row.
For Http GET request i need to display the image, but i am required to create a qustom query so that if i want to get original image i query for that and dont load thumbnails or file name that are stored in the same table row in database.

MyFile entity:

```
@Entity
private String name;
private String mimeType;
private byte[] content;
private byte[] thumbnailSm;
private byte[] thumbnailMd;
// getters & setters
```

Repository:

```
@Component
public interface MyFileRepository extends JpaRepository<MyFile, Long> {}
```

Currently what i did in controller to get image from db:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFile(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    MyFile myFile = myFileRepository.findOne(id);
    response.setContentType(myFile.getMimetype());
    response.getOutputStream().write(myFile.getContent());
    response.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

The problem is that it loads all the content from database (thumbnails, name etc) when i only need original image.

I try to create a custom query in repository and the sql statement that i try to use is:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT content FROM file WHERE id=:id")
```

Also tried the statement, don't really know what is the difference:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT f.content FROM file f WHERE f.id=:id")
```

I get bytes from database but i can't seem to figure out how to send them from repository interface method to controller so i can display image.
I tried to use something like:

```
byte[] findFileById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

and:

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> findFileById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

So my question is, after sql query gets bytes for image from db, how can i create a sql query method to get only image from db without also loading other content (thumbnails, name etc)?
Sorry if my explanation is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work like i want by doing a sql query and setting the fields i dont want to load as null:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id, name, mime_type, content, null as thumbnail_sm, null as thumbnail_md FROM file WHERE id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
MyFile findContentById(@Param("id")Long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

When fetching an entity, all attributes are going to be loaded as well. You can set fetch strategy for column to `FetchType.LAZY`, in which case the entity attribute is loaded with a secondary select statement upon being accessed for the first time.

Check this [The best way to lazy load entity attributes using JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-lazy-load-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it did not work.
the sql query that hibernate made after i added 'FetchType.LAZY' to columns:
select myfile0_.id as id1_0_0_, myfile0_.content as content4_0_0_, myfile0_.mime_type as mime_typ5_0_0_, myfile0_.name as name6_0_0_, myfile0_.thumbnail_md as thumbnai7_0_0_, myfile0_.thumbnail_sm as thumbnai8_0_0_ from file myfile0_ where myfile0_.id=?

I have the correct SQL query statement in repo, i just need to figure out how to get byte[] response. Jpa repo supports byte (primitive types), but not byte[].